# MDX Create Member Parallelperiod

Tags: mdx, member

In my Analysis Services project operated in Microsoft Visual Studio (SQL Server BIDS), I have established an attribute named Current Date in my time dimension, which is based on a property in the DataTable. The property, created as a Named Calculation in the Data Source View, has the following Expression:

```
CASE WHEN Date=CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) THEN CONVERT(BIT,1) ELSE CONVERT(BIT,0) END
```

Then, the attribute has been added to the time hierarchy Date YMD, such that this has these levels: Year, Month, Day, Current Date.

Further, I have defined the following calculated member in a cube:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Applicants 1Y lag] AS 
(PARALLELPERIOD([Date].[Date YMD].[Year], 1), [Measures].[Applicants]);
```

It works as expected when using a date hierarchy such as Date YMD or Date YWD. However, when I use the Current Date attribute as a report filter and select True only, there is nothing. I have tried different Expressions to supplement the above member definition, but none does the trick.

```
(Measures.[Applicants 1Y lag], [Date].[Date YMD].[Current Date].Members) = (
 Measures.[Applicants],
  PARALLELPERIOD(
   [Date].[Date YMD].[Year],
   1,
   [Date].[Date YMD].[Current Date].&[1].parent)
);
```

This is one of the expressions that yield nothing. What is the correct way, please? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How are the relationships set up for your Date dimension? Is Day the key attribute, or do you have a separate key attribute?

Comment: FrankPI, thanks for your reply. Day is indeed the key attribute. The attribute relationships are as follows: Day to each of the other attributes (Current Date, Month, YearMonth), YearMonth to YearQuarter, and finally YearQuarter to Year.

Comment: My first approach would be to remove the `CurrentDate` attribute from the user hierarchies and to use it as an independent attribute.